# How to create a layout from code out of a image?

Tags: html, css

I heard it was possible to create your layout out of a image using code.
So you would have a just one image instead of images for each button, header, footer etc.

You would then give coordinates and create shapes around the object for example a button.

Is there a name for this technique I'm searching for a tutorial.

Comment: I think you're referring to sprites. Long story short, you put certain images that you use as fixed background in CSS in the same image file, and you target the right coordinates in your CSS, that way there is only 1 request needed for all of the images contained in the sprite.

Comment: interesting I will be taking a look at sprites as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I correctly understand your question. It is called "image map" .

Comment: The image map is what I need I'm very new to html5 and css3 so I will be reading a bit more about the use of it thanks ;)

Comment: Wow, +1 for this answer then, only for the deduction skills :-)